# Is it possible to open camera in iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, camera, gallery

I am able to open the gallery in swift language but not able to open the camera.

I googled and tried so many codes but still problem continues.

In one question I have found that we can't open the camera in simulator,
is that true?

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is true this must be tested on a real device

Comment: Thanks Neil for your inputs, i got the answer

Comment: No problem! Have a good day!